# boost library path include

Tags: boost, mingw

I installed boost v.1.51.0 and the directory "boost_1_51_0" is sitting under "/home/user1/boost/". To install, i merely unzipped the tar file in "/home/user1/boost/". I'm using the C++ compiler on MinGW.

Now, i'm trying to include the libraries in the code. so far i tried

```
#include </home/user1/boost/boost_1_51_0/libs/unordered/test/objects/test.hpp>  
#include </home/user1/boost/boost_1_51_0/test.hpp>
#include </home/user1/boost/test.hpp>
#include <boost/test.hpp>
```

along with some others. I even tried adding the windows location of "/home/user1/boost/" to the path.

I'm missing something.

Comment: no, all on command line for now. the MinGW shell.

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide the include directory to your compiler using a command-line argument, e.g. `-I/home/user1/boost/boost_1_51_0`.

You may also want to actually install boost to a system directory; see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/bbv2/installation.html for details.

Comment: the bootstrap.sh is giving error libraries. the log file reads at the end:

Comment: the bootstrap.sh is giving error on libraries. the log file reads at its end:

    "...builtins.

    c:33:23: fatal error: 

    sys/wait.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    execunix.c:17:26: fatal error: sys/resource.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    fileunix.c:98:17: fatal error: ar.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated."

i followed the instructions on the link you gave. tried to run bootstrap at /home/user1/boost/boost_1_51_0 and got the same error.

Answer (score 3):

Use the inclusions specified in the `boost` documentation (typically along the lines of your `<boost/test.hpp>` example above).  But set your `CPPPATH`/`CXXFLAGS` (build environment) appropriately.  For `MinGW`, you'll want to add `-I/home/user1/boost/boost_1_51_0/`.

Comment: the build environment is giving me errors on library files on installation. see comment below. i used the installation instructions at the URL.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include </home/user1/boost/boost_1_51_0/libs/unordered/test/objects/test.hpp>
```

This is not going to work. That file might be found, but then it will try to include other files such as `<boost/config.hpp>` which can't be found in your include path.

```
#include </home/user1/boost/boost_1_51_0/test.hpp>
                                         ^^^^^^^^
```

This is not going to work because the file isn't at that location! if you run `ls /home/user1/boost/boost_1_51_0/test.hpp` you'll get an error because that file doesn't exist.

```
#include </home/user1/boost/test.hpp>
                            ^^^^^^^^
```

Same problem here.

It's usually a bad idea to put absolute paths in `#include` directives anyway, so all the above attempts are wrong. Instead you should include the file as its intended to be used:

```
#include <boost/test.hpp>
```

For this to work you need to tell the compiler where to look, so you set the include path with `-I dir` which in your case needs to be `-I /home/user1/boost/boost_1_51_0/` so the compiler looks for `boost/test.hpp` in `/home/user1/boost/boost_1_51_0/` and finds `/home/user1/boost/boost_1_51_0/boost/test.hpp` and when that includes `boost/config.hpp` it will find `/home/user1/boost/boost_1_51_0/boost/config.hpp` as intended.

However, now this will find `/home/user1/boost/boost_1_51_0/boost.test.hpp` but you seem to want to include a header used by one of the Boost.Undordered unit tests ... I'm not sure why you think you want that. Usually you only want to include Boost headers under `boost` not under `libs`

Comment: Thx for response. the comp.directive 

    `-I /home/user1/boost/boost_1_51_0/boost/config.hpp`

works. however, it allows me to headers in  

    `/home/user1/boost/boost_1_51_0/boost/ only.` 

I thought (?) im supposed to define a "boost-root" directory somewhere s.t. when i refer to a library from within the code, like "#include <test.hpp>", that file wld be looked up in "boost-root" and all its subdirs. 

I don't think I missed anything on MinGW. But something is wrong w/Boost installation. 

i wasn't aware that i was using a header from Boost.Undordered. on a

Comment: ... quick look-up, it's an alternative to bin.tree search on STL and looks to be a fine one. Is it/not totally compatible, does it add much extra burden? Why wld i avoid using it ?

I got a code that I'm working on and it's using the Boost library including AudioStreamInput.h, Metadata.h, etc. Will also use the thread library, but couldn't get passes these yet.

Comment: Oh dear. I think you've completely failed to understand my answer. The whole point of the `-I /home/user1/boost/boost_1_51_0/` is to define a "boost root" for the headers. I never told you to use `-I /home/user1/boost/boost_1_51_0/boost/config.hpp` (that's a file not a directory!) or `-I /home/user1/boost/boost_1_51_0/boost` (that's not the right directory).

Comment: And I didn't say you shouldn't use Boost.Unordered. I said you shouldn't use headers from its unit tests. If you want to use Boost.Unordered then follow [its documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/unordered.html#unordered.intro) and use `#include <boost/unordered_set.hpp>` or `#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>`, don't use `#include <libs/unordered/test/objects/test.hpp>`

Comment: a quick note, `-I /home/user1/boost/boost_1_51_0/boost/` is the directive i used and the compiler error is _fatal error: boost/test.hpp no such file or dir ..._ . 

`-I /home/user1/boost/boost_1_51_0/boost/config.hpp` is a mistake i've done cutting and pasting thru windows.

Comment: As I said originally, it should be `-I /home/user1/boost/boost_1_51_0` **not** `-I /home/user1/boost/boost_1_51_0/boost`, it's not difficult, just think about it: if you want to include `/foo/bar/baz.hpp` and the source code says `#include <bar/baz.hpp>` then you need to use `-I /foo` because `/foo` plus `bar/baz.hpp` equals `/foo/bar/baz.hpp`

Comment: k, thanks again. let me see this some and will probably figure. 

my "theory" that something on the installation setup to describe a path to all directories fails & there probably isn't anything wrong with boost setup. but then bootstrap.sh didn't run. 

when i `#include <boost/unordered_set.hpp>`, does it totally "override" the STL look-up ? when i'm referring to STL now, is it searched through the hast-tables of Boost.unordered ?

Comment: all fine now about the paths to headers-- looked at the .hpp file contents at boost/ directory. 

...

Comment: re. Boost.unordered, from what i know so far, Boost.unordered is another STL look-up mechanism. it uses hash-tables for searching STL as opposed to binary search of the default STL look-up.

i was wondering whether it is fully "compatible", that is do i miss anything on STL use if i use it with Boost.unordered?

Comment: It's not a "look-up mechanism" it's a library of containers, `unordered_set` and `unordered_map`. They have many similarities to the standard library containers `set` and `map`, and some differences too. Look for other questions or ask a new one to understand those differences - trying to explain it in comments here is not going to work.

Comment: will do. something still wrong with Boost installation and it's not working.